# I can try use xmllint but not found

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I can try use xmllint for transform XML on SQL.

I have this XML and i need transform in SQL.

```
 <CommunicationLog xmlns="http://knx.org/xml/telegrams/01">
  <RecordStart Timestamp="" Mode="" Host="" ConnectionName="" ConnectionOptions="" ConnectorType="" MediumType="" />
  <Telegram Timestamp="" Service="" FrameFormat="" RawData="" />
  <Telegram Timestamp="" Service="" FrameFormat="" RawData="" />
  <RecordStart Timestamp="" Mode="" Host="" ConnectionName="" ConnectionOptions="" ConnectorType="" MediumType="" />
  <Telegram Timestamp="" Service="" FrameFormat="" RawData="" />
  <Telegram Timestamp="" Service="" FrameFormat="" RawData="" />
  <RecordStop Timestamp="" />
</CommunicationLog>
```

I have this script in bash with xmllint for transform

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$1"
table=$(xmllint --xpath "name()" "$file")
value=$(xmllint --xpath "//*/*/text()" "$file")

cat << EOF
INSERT INTO \`${table}\`
VALUES
(${value})
EOF
```

And my output:

```
XPath set is empty
```

I can try use XML_LOAD(); in sql server but not found me. Data is deleted because it is private.

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting with this `XPath`?

```
//*/*/text()
```

This will do a **deep search** for **any node**, then go one node deeper and take the `text()`.

Your XML is attribute centered... And there is a default namespace (`xmlns`)...

I have no idea, what you want to achieve. Just for testing you might try something like this

```
/*:CommunicationLog/*:*/@*:Timestamp
```

The `*:` is a wildcard for the namespace (but better declare it properly!). It will start at `<CommunicationLog>` and iterate through all nodes below. All of them seem to have a timestamp-attribute. This should return something...

If you don't find your way out, please insert some dummy data to your XML and state the expected output.